# multiple swf communication using as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

**My need :** 
   If I playing one swf, the other swfs should pause if it was playing.

I can able to communicate two swfs using javascript(both swfs are different name). But come to multiple swfs, I don't know how to differentiate the swfs beacause all are same name.

I have embed 3 swf files in my html page using the following script.

```
swfobject.embedSWF('http://webserver/aruldass/versemusic/modules/mod_playerjr/player-songs.swf', 'jwplayer1', '280', '230', '9', false, flashvars, params, attributes); 

swfobject.embedSWF('http://webserver/aruldass/versemusic/modules/mod_playerjr/player-songs.swf', 'jwplayer2', '280', '230', '9', false, flashvars, params, attributes); 

swfobject.embedSWF('http://webserver/aruldass/versemusic/modules/mod_playerjr/player-songs.swf', 'jwplayer3', '280', '230', '9', false, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

I want to communicate each other.

Share your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think I would solve this problem the following way:

- Modify the SWF to generate a random id upon creation.
- Add a JavaScript function that has an id-value as parameter and calls a pre-defined function on ALL the SWF (let's say `processPlayEvent(id:String):void`
- Use the Flash `ExternalInterface` to call that function passing the current SWF Id as a parameter
- Inside the `processPlayEvent` function you check if the provided id equals the one of the current movie. If they are unequal, you halt the playback of the current SWF.