# How to pass variable From one Swf to another Swf in ActionScript3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have two swf(a.swf anb b.swf) in as3 . Now I want  pass variable From  a.swf to b.Swf.i follow this link [Tutorial](http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2009/02/passing-parameters-to-loaded-swf.html) 
i used the Loader Class.Here my Coding.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load("a.swf?test=hi");
```

But i got Error Message

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "textchat.swf?test=hi" to flash.net.URLRequest.
>       at BasicTickerSprite_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

How Can i rectify this problem?How Can i pass a String From one Swf to another Swf?
Anyone Kindly Explain me in Detail
Thaks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

Check out [flash.net.LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6)

Comment: I up voted, because this is the right way to do it.  However, in the future, try to give a little more information such as a simple example or a link to an explanation of how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

ExternalInterface is a good approach.

Perhaps better yet would be the LocalConnection class:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html

Maybe a good start to understand basic concepts is from this answer provided here at Stack Overflow:

[How to pass a String from a SWF into another SWF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933387/how-to-pass-a-string-from-a-swf-into-another-swf)

Answered by Plastic Sturgeon:

> Let's clarify a bit: 1. The loader swf, we will call the parent. 2.
>   The swf loaded by the parent we will call the child.
>
> The Child contains a string, and you want the parent to be able to
>   read that string> So... The Child must define a public variable for
>   the string. (This means you have to use a Class file for it, since you
>   cannot declare a property public on the timeline.)
>
> Finally, the parent will try and get that property. You may want to
>   wrap that in a try/catch to handle cases where the string will not be
>   present.
>
> Here is an example Child Class.
>
> ```
> package  
> {
> import flash.display.Sprite;
>
> /**
>  * ...
>  * @author Zach Foley
>  */
> public class Child extends Sprite 
> {
>     public var value:String = "This is the child Value";
>     public function Child() 
>     {
>         trace("Child Loaded");
>     }
>
> }
> }
> ```
>
> And here is the parent loader class:
>
> ```
> package  
> {
> import flash.display.Loader;
> import flash.display.Sprite;
> import flash.events.Event;
> import flash.net.URLRequest;
>
> /**
>  * ...
>  * @author Zach Foley
>  */
> public class Parent extends Sprite 
> {
>     private var loader:Loader;
>
>     public function Parent() 
>     {
>         trace("PArent Init");
>         loader = new Loader();
>         loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
>         loader.load(new URLRequest("child.swf"));
>     }
>
>     private function onLoaded(e:Event):void 
>     {
>         trace("Child Loaded");
>         trace(loader.content['value']);
>     }
>
> }
> }
> ```
>
> The Output will be: PArent Init Child Loaded Child Loaded This is the
>   child Value

Comment: +1 Thanks for ur kind reply, It's very useful information for me.i declare a variable in a.swf var value:String = "This is the child Value"; Now i cal the value in B.swf,Here my Coding         function onLoaded(e:Event):void 
    {
        trace("Child Loaded");
        trace(loader.content['value']);
    }

    loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
        loader.load(new URLRequest("a.swf"));

Comment: i got error message Also TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at textchat_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Answer (score 1):

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("http//localhost/a.swf?test=hi"));
```

you'll need a local server for it
**update**:

```
    private var _ldr:Loader;
    private var _mc:MovieClip;
    public function Main():void {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point
        _ldr = new Loader();
        _ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onInit);
        _ldr.load(new URLRequest('a.swf'));
    }

    private function onInit(e:Event):void{
        _mc = _ldr.content as MovieClip;
        _mc['test'] = 'hi';
        addChild(_mc);
    }
```

Comment: I tried this coding ,i got error like this,Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.

Comment: Again Same Error Occured sir.Kindly help me.i Connected my Local Server

Comment: does the same url open in web browser?

Comment: Ya Same url Sir,Is any other Way to pass the String from one Swf to another Swf in as3?Kindly Guide me

Answer (score 0):

You can attain better communication between SWFs using `ExternalInterface` object.

Look at [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) for adobe reference.

and take a look at following links.

- [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994466/multiple-swf-communication)
- [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011043/how-to-get-the-swf-name-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic but I recently had to reference a smartfox server instance and variables between multiple swfs.  I thought i'd share the basics on how i achieved this.

ParentSWF

```
public var MyVar:String = "Hello";
public var sfs:SmartFox = new SmartFox(true);
private var ChildMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
private var myLoader:Loader;

private function LoadChildSWF(evt:Event):void //i used button click event to load swf
    {
    myLoader = new Loader();                     // create a new instance of the Loader class
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("YOURSWF.swf"); // in this case both SWFs are in the same folder
    try
        {
            myLoader.load(url);
            myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,FFLoaded);

        } 
        catch (error:Error) 
        {
            trace("Unable to load requested document.");
        }
    }
    function FFLoaded(e:Event):void
    {
        ChildMC= myLoader.content as MovieClip;
        addChild(ChildMC);
        ChildMC.init(this);

    }
    public function RemoveChildMC():void
    {
        removeChild(ChildMC);
        ChildMC=null;
    }
```

ChildSWF

```
package
{
import com.smartfoxserver.v2.SmartFox;

public class ChildDocumentClass extends MovieClip
{
    private var refDocument:*;
    private var ChildVar:String;
    private var sfs:SmartFox;
    public function ChildDocumentClass()
    {
        trace("Initilise ChildDocumentClass");
        // Nothing to do
    }
    public function init(refDoc:*):void
    {
        // Get the references to the Document Class
        refDocument = refDoc;
        // Get the references to the Server Instance
        sfs=refDocument.sfs;
    //Pass Parent Variable to child variable 
        ChildVar=refDocument.MyVar;
    }
//call to parent class function example to remove loaded swf
    private function UnloadThisSWF():void
    {
        refDocument.RemoveChildMC();
    }
}
}
```

As you can see communication can be achieved by passing the parent class to the child class through the init(refDoc:*) function.